# Eigenvalues of (f•g)

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there any general relation between the eigenvalues of a endomorphism ***f***, the ones of an other endomorphism ***g*** in the same vector space and the eigenvalues of ***(f•g)***, or ***(g•f)***? (Without assuming that ***f*** or ***g*** are necessarily diagonalizable)

Comment: There are some inequalities, I believe, that bound the eigenvalues. However, there are no useful guaranteed equalities unless we assume that $f$ and $g$ commute.

Comment: It is notable, of course, that $\det(f \circ g) = \det(f) \det(g)$, and that the determinant is the product of eigenvalues.